# What type of information i can collect from the ip and mac address in my local network?

Tags: networking

I want to know the device information such as vendor, device type (Mobile, PC, Router, Switches, location, etc) information through the IP and mac address.
is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out some of that information by using this tool https://www.ipchecktool.com/tool/macfinder